# Have a landingpage on a different domain

Tags: multistore, redirect

My client wants landingpages on a different domain using content within magento. I'm familiar with multi-store setups but this is not ideal becouse of duplicate content and Payment service provider restrictions. What i'm trying to accomplish is showing one CMS page on a different domain. When the visitor clicks a link it has to be redirected to the main domain. Google must also index the links to the main domain.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way you could do this fully under one installation of Magento due to the drawbacks you mention, however, depending on how you want to create the alternate site, you could potentially load product information in periodically via the Magento API and store them somewhere for the second site to access?  Alternatively, if both domains are on the same site and you don;t have any openbase_dir restrictions, you could call Mage and interact as any external script would.

Answer (score 1):

Would for sure recommend a landing page builder option as an easier route. You can setup as many pages as you want with Instapage, check it out for free here:

http://www.instapage.com/?utm_source=forum&utm_medium=engagement&utm_campaign=Forum%20Comment

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can't because of the way Magento works internally, you need a landing page builder like LeadPages or Unbounce. The sites we work on do have this which shows the content on the subdomain with site header/footer but all menus are of the main domain, but it's part of a complete architecture so not portable. You can also try WP multisite but like the page builders it's not integrated in to the site.